# Breaking down a large String in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to enable my users to edit their order history from a control panel on my site. Currently when a user places an order this script is executed:

```
function process_order_form_handler() {

    //Get form Data from POST array
    $orderArray = json_decode(urldecode($_POST['product_list']),true);
    $orderHistory = $orderArray;

    $comment = $_POST['comments'];
    $delivery = $_POST['next-day-delivery'];

    $id = $_POST['CMP_Member'];

    //Loop through the Array
    if(is_array($orderArray)){
    //Order Code
    $orderRequestCode = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s');
    //Get customer information here - email....
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $customerName =  $user->user_firstname . " " . $user->user_lastname;
    $customerEmail = $user->user_email;

    $user_ID = $user->ID;

    //Order history functionality
         add_user_meta($user->ID, "Order", $orderHistory, true);

    //Get the order Items
    echo "This is the order: ";

    $orderContent = "Order Code: " . $orderRequestCode."\r\n";
    $orderContent .= "Customer Name: " . $customerName . "\r\n";
    $orderContent .= "Customer Email: " . $customerEmail . "\r\n";
    if($delivery == 'yes'){
        $orderContent .= "Next Day Delivery: " . $delivery . "\r\n";
    }

    $orderContent .= "Order Items: " . "\r\n";


    foreach($orderArray as $item){
        if($item['bulk'] == 'true'){
        $orderContent .= "Stock Code: " . $item['stockCode'] . " Quantity: " . $item['quantity'] . " Bulk Order";
        if($item['sbulk']){//if true then sharing split bulk
           $orderContent .= " Sharing: " . $item['share'] . " Qty: " . $item['sharequantity'] . "\r\n";
        }else{
            $orderContent .= "\r\n";
        }
        }else{
        $orderContent .= "Stock Code: " . $item['stockCode'] . " Quantity: " . $item['quantity'] . "\r\n";  
        }
    }

    //Comments
    $orderContent .= "Comments: " . "\r\n";
    $orderContent .= $comment;

    $orderContent = wordwrap($orderContent, 70, "\r\n");

    //Once everything is done send to the users email address
    $headers =  'From: sales@mushrooms.ie' . "\r\n" .       
                    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    // Send to Customer
    mail($customerEmail, 'Order Confirmation', $orderContent, $headers);


    //Send to the Sales dept.
    //mail('xxx@xxx.xxx', 'Order ' . $orderRequestCode, $orderContent, $headers);

    //Create Custom Post of the order
    $my_post = array(
            'post_title' => $orderRequestCode.' - ' . $customerName,
            'post_content' => $orderContent,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_author' => $user_ID,
            'post_type' => 'orders'
        );

    var_dump($my_post);

    // Insert the post into the database
    wp_insert_post( $my_post);

    //Delete Cookie

        unset($_COOKIE['order_cookie']);
    setcookie('order_cookie', '', time() - 3600);

    //Redirect to Dashboard
    wp_redirect( home_url().'?processed=true');
    exit;
    }
}
?>
```

This gives me an object that looks like this, when I retrieve it from my `database` using `wordpress` `get_post($orderID);`.

```
object(WP_Post)[325]
  public 'ID' => int 1058
  public 'post_author' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'post_date' => string '2014-06-18 08:05:23' (length=19)
  public 'post_date_gmt' => string '2014-06-18 08:05:23' (length=19)
  public 'post_content' => string 'Order Code: 2014-06-18-08-05-20
Customer Name: Jack Coldrick
Customer Email: jack@xxx.ie
Next Day Delivery: yes
Order Items: 
Stock Code: G992/75BLK Quantity: 10
Stock Code: NETT FILM JMC Quantity: 6
Stock Code: WW42 Quantity: 4
Comments: 
' (length=254)
  public 'post_title' => string '2014-06-18-08-05-20 - Jack Coldrick' (length=35)
  public 'post_excerpt' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'post_status' => string 'publish' (length=7)
  public 'comment_status' => string 'open' (length=4)
```

I want my users to be able to edit their order so what I am currently doing is getting a reference to the `order_content` information in the above object.

```
string 'Order Code: 2014-06-18-08-05-20
Customer Name: Jack Coldrick
Customer Email: jack@xxx.ie
Next Day Delivery: yes
Order Items: 
Stock Code: G992/75BLK Quantity: 10
Stock Code: NETT FILM JMC Quantity: 6
Stock Code: WW42 Quantity: 4
Comments: Test Comment 123
' (length=254)
```

I would then essentially need to store each piece of this `String` in `variables` and populate an edit order form using these `variables`. My question is what is the best way to break down this String in an efficient and effective way? For example to get my Customers Name I'd ideally like to do something like

```
`$customerName = ???`
`echo $customerName;` //returns Jack Coldrick
```

Comment: Why must it be one large string? Can you not POST the data as indicidual variables? It would make validation/verification/storage/retrieval a lot easier.

Comment: Ignore my comment above, WP is a horrible way to do a shopping cart, it is a blogging platform afterall. Perhaps you should look into splitting the string between 'Customer Name' and 'customer email', then between 'customer email' and 'next day delivery' and so on, and storing those into variables. A kludge, yes it is; workable, yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing us is a `\WP_Post` object that already is split apart into individual properties. WordPress also has a [Revision system](http://codex.wordpress.org/Revisions) for posts. You just have to enable them in your `wp-config.php`.

```
define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', 3 );
```

Every time you update a (custom) post type, WordPress takes the old version and saves it as new row in your `{$prefix}_posts` table as `revision`. You also have a UI to diff versions and rollback to old versions.